# JavaScript In UserControl Wont Run

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to run the following script from my usercontrol:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function RebindUpdatePanelControls(sender, args) {
        $("#divUpload2").hide();
        $("#divUpload3").hide();
        alert("Hi Neck");

        $('#lnkMore').click(function () {
            if ($('#hfClicked').val() == "0") {
                $("#divUpload2").slideToggle();
                $('#hfClicked').val("1");
            }
            else if ($('#hfClicked').val() == "1") {
                $("#divUpload3").slideToggle();
                $('#hfClicked').val("2");
            }

        });

    }

</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
Sys.Application.add_load(RebindUpdatePanelControls); 
</script>
```

I added it to the top of the usercontrol file but it will not run

lnkMore looks like this:

```
  <input id="lnkMore" type="button" value="Add GCM File"  />
```

Is there something else I am missing to do to get this running?

How do I make the client side button use this code when it isclicked?

Comment: I see your function, but no code that actually CALLS it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     <input id="lnkMore" type="button" value="Add GCM File" onclick="clickfunction()" />


     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
         function clickfunction() {
         if ($('#hfClicked').val() == "0") {
            $("#divUpload2").slideToggle();
            $('#hfClicked').val("1");
        }
        else if ($('#hfClicked').val() == "1") {
            $("#divUpload3").slideToggle();
            $('#hfClicked').val("2");
        }

    });

}

  </script>
```